# Python: Comando import fica em cinza no PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Instalei o Python 3 e o PyCharm e o comando "import" estava funcionando normalmente. De alguns dias pra cá, toda vez que tento importar alguma biblioteca, por exemplo, import datetime, assim que aperto o Enter, o comando fica em cinza.

Será que desabilitei alguma coisa?

[image: screenshot do editor]

Comment: Isso acontece em todas as linhas?

Comment: Não, só na primeira linha. Também fiz essa pergunta para um colega e ele me disse que o import vai ficar cinza até que eu utilize uma das funções, aí o comando import volta a ficar colorido. Interessante isso. Apanhando e aprendendo rssss... Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

No Pycharm, quando o import esta cinza, significa que ele nao está sendo utilizado...

Se voce utilizá-lo de qualquer forma, por exemplo:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

ele ficará colorido.

O Pycharm disponibiliza alguns plugins para facilitar sua vida... Um deles, é o [SonarLint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint), que mostra alguns possíves erros, assim como imports não utilizados.